# .net WebApi - wrong value of HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I am using `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath` function in order to locate a resource in a site hosted by IIS.

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("localPath")
```

The value that I get from it is:

`c:\users\guy\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\api\localPath`

while the real content is in

`C:\Users\guy\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\localPath`

Why do I get an extra `api` in the end? maybe it has something to do with the fact I am running a webapi app?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show with what values and how you call that method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably need to add `~/` to get to the root folder. Like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/")
```